# Is learning about kissing before marriage through text-only haraam?

Tags: halal-haram, kissing

Recently I have been curious about knowing how do people kiss. I have read it on a website that it's okay to learn through websites but not through pictures and videos only when you are about to marry. So I want to know if it is okay to learn through websites through reading.

Although I'm in my 20's but not about to marry in the near future. I'm just curious to know how kissing is done.

I would like to know if it is halal or haram? If it is haram is there a halal way of learning *"how to kiss"* ? if yes what is it?

If there is no way then when, from whom and how do you need to learn about kissing?

Answer (score -1):

If your intention is just to learn, and to only do it with your future wife/husband, and without any sexually stimulating content, then you obviously can learn about kissing, since you will need it in your future relationship, just how Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him used to brush his teeth with miswak when he comes from work and kiss his wife ‘Aisha a very good kiss (equivalent to a french kiss today).

Comment: @june Havens but you have not to learn it from videos.